# Is it possible to make colors invisible in the code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, image-manipulation

For a game that I am currently making, I have a black background with many white dots, which are being used to represent stars. I have no need for the black color however, and I only wish for the stars to show. My question is this: Is it possible to completely hide the black color without using an image manipulation program, that is, using only code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean you don't want the black background? Should it be white or clear (no color)? Please elaborate a bit. (If it's white the stars will not be visible obviously)

Comment: Please excuse my lack of description, what I meant to say was that I wish to remove the black and leave full transparency in its place. This would leave only the white stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the form:

```
// some rgba color representation
struct t_rgba {
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;
};

bool SetToTransparentIfPixelIsBlack(t_rgba* const rgba) {
    // is it black?
    if (0 == rgba->r && 0 == rgba->g && 0 == rgba->b) {
        // then set the alpha value to transparent:
        rgba->a = 0;
    }
}
```

although the image data you are using will be represented differently.

Comment: thanks, but the declaration of that struct doesnt actually assign every pixel in the image to its correct value, does it?

Comment: it sets the alpha of the black pixels to 0. adapt for your needs.